# Preventing duplicates while selecting into variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, loops, duplicates

My function generates unique combinations from `Items` table and stores into `list` variable. In the end of generation, it returns `list` as a result and application processes every combination: saves into `Combo` table.

## The Problem

It checks every time for duplicates from another tables called `Combo` which is getting filled in the second step of process (by application, not by function itself.)

**But,** It doesn't check for duplicates **inside `list`variable** before inserting into it newly generated combinations.

So I'm getting result from function with duplicates inside the result itself. For example. `3423` appears here in the result 2 times:

```
3410;3463;3423;3489;3446;3445;3417;3436;3497;3454;3491;3420;3502;3496;3458;3493;3439;3499;3497;3487;3486;3504;3458;3501;3503;3441;3443;3453;3508;3474;3469;3497;3508;3433;3451;3449;3422;3453;3428;3475;3474;3458;3480;3422;3488;3432;3501;3414;3425;3444;3509;3502;3440;3422;3472;3501;3477;3483;3449;3480;3456;3463;3493;3476;3479;3425;3485;3464;3410;3434;3488;3504;3439;3423;3434;3486;3448;3456;3496;3413;3428;3482;3439;3437;3473;3420;3439;3470;3463;3494;3415;3442;3428;3500;3488;3478;3475;3417;3472;3463
```

How can I check `list` itself for duplicates before insertion?

## Details

My function:

```
SELECT gen_n_uniq_perms_by_cat(1, 100, 1, 45, 1, 120, 20) as comb
```

which look like:

```
BEGIN

SET @result := "";


SET @counter := 0;

iterat :
LOOP
    SELECT
        gen_uniq_perm_by_cat(
            permSize ,
            user_id ,
            catID ,
            itemType ,
            tsc_id ,
            tries
        ) INTO @combo;


IF(ISNULL(@combo)) THEN
    RETURN @result;


ELSE

SET @result := CONCAT_WS(';' ,@result ,@combo);


END
IF;


SET @counter := @counter + 1;


IF @counter > permCount THEN
    RETURN @result;


END
IF;


END
LOOP
    iterat;


END
```

and `gen_uniq_perm_by_cat` looks like:

```
BEGIN
    iterat :
LOOP
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            GROUP_CONCAT(`id` ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR '-') ,
            '-' ,
            permSize
        ) INTO @list
    FROM
        `Item`
    LEFT JOIN `ItemCategory` ON `Item`.`id` = `ItemCategory`.`itemID`
    WHERE
        (`Item`.`user_id` = user_id)
    AND(`ItemCategory`.`catID` = catID)
    AND(`Item`.`type` = itemType);


SET @md5 := MD5(CONCAT_WS('-' , @list , tsc_id));


IF(
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        `Combo`
    WHERE
        `Combo`.`hash` = @md5
    LIMIT 1
) = 0 THEN
    RETURN @list;


END
IF;


SET tries := tries - 1;


IF tries = 0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;


END
IF;


END
LOOP
    iterat;


END
```

generates unique (never created in past) combinations by following arguments:

```
permSize = 1
permCount =100
user_id = 1
catID = 45
itemType = 1
tsc_id = 120
tries = 20
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. But `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)` will remove the duplicated ids.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel All I want to do is, to check `list` variable for duplicates before inserting new combination into it. If there is duplicate, then continue looping until we get `permCount ` number of combinations. If `tries` time we fail to pick  unique combination (that is not inside `list` or `Combo` table) then we quit.

Comment: So would it be wrong to just remove the duplicates instead of executing the query again?

Comment: The `list` is `;` separated combinations string. So what you suggest is, to remove every time duplicates from this list? or what? I think, logically checking before inserting new combination would be right.

Comment: `DISTINCT` would eliminate duplicates before the concatenation.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Sir, `DISTINCT` has no effect on it. `list` is getting filled by every loop. So basically, list gets every time value from new query. I want to check new combination with existing ones inside `list` before adding to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139997/discussion-between-demonoid-and-paul-spiegel).

Comment: I updated the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235774/preventing-duplicates-while-selecting-into-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT LIKE` for this purpose. In your case, replace corresponding condition lines with following:

```
IF(ISNULL(@combo)) THEN
    RETURN @result;
END IF;


IF(@result NOT LIKE CONCAT('%' , @combo , '%')) THEN
    SET @result := CONCAT_WS(';' ,@result ,@combo);
    SET @counter := @counter + 1;
END IF;


IF @counter = permCount THEN
    RETURN @result;
END IF;
```